# Question about basis of the euclidean topology.

Tags: general-topology

I know that a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is open if and only if it is a union of open intervals **(I know how to prove this)**. So $B_1=\{(a,b):a,b\in \mathbb{R},a<b\}$ is basis for the eucliden topology because the union of members of this basis can form any open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. But $B_1=\{(a,b):a,b\in \mathbb{Q},a<b\}$ should also be a basis for the euclidean topology since it is an open interval and any open subset can be thought as the union of open intervals. Is there anything tricky here I am not considering? Because I don't think this is a proof.

Comment: It is indeed a basis. Also note that it is numerable,  which is an important topological property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $B_1$ is also a base for the Euclidean topology. There's no contradiction: a topology can have more than one base.

(In fact, let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and let $I_A=\{(a, b): a, b\in A\}.$ Then $I_A$ is a base for the Euclidean topology iff $A$ is *dense*. So, for instance, we can replace the rationals with the dyadic rationals, or similar.)

However, your reasoning is a bit over the place. You write:

> $B_1$ . . . should also be a base for the euclidean topology since it is an open interval and any open subset can be thought as the union of open intervals.

This isn't right.

- $B_1$ isn't an open interval, it's a *set of* open intervals.
- What this tells us is that the topology generated by $B_1$ is a *subset* of the Euclidean topology, so now we just need to show the other direction.
- It's not enough to say that "any open set can be thought of as the union of open intervals" - you need to say that any open set is the union of open intervals *from $B_1$*, and this takes proof: how would you write $(\sqrt{2}, \pi)$ as a union of intervals with rational endpoints?
- That almost finishes the proof - now we know that $B_1$ generates the Euclidean topology. But all this shows is that $B_1$ is a *subbase* for the Euclidean topology - to show that it's a base, we need to show that it's closed under finite intersections.